# EF database-first approach how to add new not null column to production table and manage at code level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

My ASP.NET MVC 4 application uses Entity Framework 6 and a database-first approach. It is already in production environment, and now wants to add new column to the `Deposit` table and this column is not null. The production table already has a lot of data.

How should I manage this changes, in code-first approach, can anyone help me out? What should I do, I am new to Entity Framework.

Comment: Are you going to change database-first approach to code-first approach?

Comment: How are you migrating database changes now?  By hand?  Using a tool like DbGhost/Redgate/Apex?  I'm assuming you aren't using ef migrations since you are new to ef.

Comment: No, i am not changing approach to code first and not using any tool, just wanted to handle this situation but as i am new to EF don`t know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you will continue to use the database-first approach  you can do something like that:

1) run a script to migrate DB:

```
ALTER TABLE Deposit ADD <column_name> INT NULL
GO
UPDATE Deposit SET <a valid not null values for your column>
GO
ALTER TABLE Deposit  ALTER COLUMN <column_name> INT NOT NULL
GO
```

2) Since you are using the db-first approach you need update `edmx` model (`.edmx` file) which is already attached to db. If I remember correctly, you can do it from context menu in Solution Explorer.